# Produce new array where all positive comes first, then negative or zero but in same order

Tags: arrays, scala

This is problem from [Scala for the Impatient](http://www.horstmann.com/scala/index.html), chapter of Arrays stated as

> Given an array of integers, produce a new array that contains all
>   positive values of the original array, in their original order,
>   followed by all values that are zero or negative, in their original
>   order.

My attempt is

```
scala> val b = Array(-1, 2,3,4, -10, 0, -12)
b: Array[Int] = Array(-1, 2, 3, 4, -10, 0, -12)

scala> val(positive, negative) = b partition(_ > 0)
positive: Array[Int] = Array(2, 3, 4)
negative: Array[Int] = Array(-1, -10, 0, -12)

scala> positive ++ negative
res11: Array[Int] = Array(2, 3, 4, -1, -10, 0, -12)
```

Can I do this better in one line? I am not sure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider `filter` and `filterNot` as follows,

```
b.filter(_ > 0) ++ b.filterNot(_ > 0)
```

Comment: very neat @elem. Thanks a lot

Comment: Why filterNot(), it can be achieved using filter only. `arr.filter(_ > 0) ++ arr.filter(_ <= 0)`

Answer (score 2):

`b.sorted(Ordering.by((_: Int) <= 0))`

Method `sorted` returns the sorted array according to an Ordering (which says that positive numbers have lower order than zero or negative), without modifying the original array.

Comment: you need to add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Seems the very simple if you use the filters. My version:

```
def result(a: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = a.filter(_ > 0) ++ a.filter(_ <= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b.sortWith((l, r) => if(l > 0 && r < 1) true else false)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can assign 1 if value is positive and 0 otherwise using `max(0, x.sign)` to distinguish between them. Because we want positive values first (descending order) we prepend our `max` with a minus. The solution then simplifies to:

```
b.sortBy(x => -max(0, x.sign))
```

Sorting in Scala is stable so the original order will persist.